# What compiler options used to compile C++ STL classes/functions in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, stl, compilation

I have a C++ app for Windows.
In Visual Studio I can change configuration of compiler including optimization options (i.e. /O1 /O2 etc.). After that all my source code will be compiled as I wish.

But what about functions/classes from STL? As I understand some of them not templates but regular C++ functions. Are they pre-built somehow? What compiler options used to compile them? Can I can change these config?

Comment: IIRC, even some of the template classes are pre-built, in particular `std::basic_string<char>` aka `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are pre-built in a non-documented process. You are not supposed to redo this, but have to trust the compiler team to know the proper settings. :-)

If you look in your Visual Studio program folder, the libraries are in the `VC/lib` folder, and all the sources in `VC/crt/src`.